# this error is hitting continuously even after importing ReactiveFormModule , groupForm and ControlForm ,what to do

Tags: angular

Error: src/app/login2/login2.component.html:2:8 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

2 <form  [formGroup]="grpForm">

Comment: are you importing ReactiveFormModule in app.module.ts and then adding it in imports array too in the same file ?

Comment: yes I have register the file in import array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error usually shows up when you do not create an instance formGroup in your component.ts, or you have not generated your form inside the .ts file correctly or you have some typo and name conflicts, since it is not clear what exactly you did I will guide you generally.
consider this that you have to import 'FormGroup' module from '@angular/forms' and declare it to 'grpForm' (or whatever you named you Form) in your component.ts file as its type like:

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

grpForm: FormGroup;
```

Also keep in mind that you have to initial your form inside ngOnInit() and put your form input 'formControlName':

```
this.grpForm= new FormGroup({
  example1: new FormControl(null),
  example2: new FormControl(null),
});
```